# Can I resize an image (Drawing file) in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, image-manipulation

Is it possible to resize an image (a Drawing file) within Google Drive?

I created a new drawing in Google Drive. When I download the image as a PNG file and then upload it to where I want to use it (Google+ profile), the image seems to be too large (Google+ is cropping the edges out). I would like to try to reduce the size of the image before downloading the PNG.

Note: I am doing this using only online tools since I am working on a Chromebook. Otherwise I would just use a desktop application to change the image size. Suggestions for other online tools that I can use to resize the image are also welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't know how to change the image within Google Drive, but there are several online services for re sizing images, I've use this one and works perfectly: http://www.resizeyourimage.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I also found that if I do a Select All on the image in Google Drive it gives me grabber arrows that I can use to resize. But it's difficult to get a precise size since there is no pixel count.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Drive Drawings seem to be vectors. There is no "pixel count" for vector images.

I find that select all and resize works well for shapes but less well if I have text (especially if different text boxes have different font sizes- then I have to change the font size for each box after the resize.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the drawing in inches- centimeters, points or pixels in the File->Page Setup menu.

I know this question is currently nine years old but Google pointed me here so I will get a current answer in here.

Answer (score 0):

What I use and works great is 
[Online Image Resizer](http://www.image-resizer.eu).

Simple, fast and allows also some effects.