# Re-sizing my photos in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I too have a problem with Google Drive storage in that all my photos have been automatically uploaded to Google Drive at full size taking up almost 100% of my 15GB storage quota.

It is possible to remedy this by:

1. Deleting all the photo files from Google Drive;
2. Then adjust the computer settings so that photo files are in future uploaded at standard size only;
3. Then re-upload all photo folders/files manually which on this second time round will be uploaded at standard size.

I would appreciate any advice from others more technically proficient than I am.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: May be here have a look at this similar discussion [resize an image in Google Drive](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29742/can-i-resize-an-image-drawing-file-in-google-drive).

Answer (score 3):

Since googledrive is accessible as a virtual drive, you should be able to use imagemagick to modify the size or compression of the images in place.

Comment: Here is more information on how to resize with [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).